# After installing opencv3.4 Centos 7 not rebooting in GUI

Tags: centos, opencv

I was already using OpenCV 2.4.5 by installing it using `yum install opencv opencv-devel`.

But I was facing some problems as it doesn't have FFmpeg. I installed OpenCV 3.4 following [this guide](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-4-4-on-centos-7/).

After following these steps I followed [guide to link share lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335848/opencv-program-compile-error-libopencv-core-so-2-4-cannot-open-shared-object-f), and I created `opencv.conf` file at

```
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf
```

and wrote the path of my libs to it that is

```
/usr/local/installation/opencv3.4/lib64
```

Then I ran

```
sudo ldconfig -v
```

It was all working fine after that and I could successfully build QT projects using new OpenCV libs.

But once I restarted my CentOS7 I got the "Oh no! Something has gone wrong" screen.

I have to install it in a system but for now, I was doing it all on Oracle VirtualBox as I can't risk it on main system. I am able to login using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. What could be the possible problem?

Comment: Does it boot if you remove `opencv.conf` from `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`?

Comment: @NasirRiley No. Now it's not booting even after I remove `opencv.conf` from `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`. Can it be a problem in X11?

Comment: What do the logs say? Add the output to your question.

Comment: How can I check log? Also how can I copy it from vm just using terminal. I may include a snap. Which log you want please let me know.

Comment: If you can log in using `CTRL ALT F1`, then you can look at `/var/log/boot.log` and `/var/log/messages` and add their contents to your question. That will give you and other a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: I rebooted my system after every step and found that error was not in OpenCV at all. As soon I run `yum -y install qt5-qtbase-devel` it updates dependencies and reinstalls x11 and x11-devel. I think that's the problem. If I skip it , I still have to do `yum -y install gtk2-devel` and it installs x11 again. Still not able to resolve it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because according to OP's comment the problem has no relation to what the title and the question suggest. No one with this problem will find this question and no one finding this question will be searching for the problem.